# how should I say climbing up or crawling up?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, difference

for example: baby crawling up  ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The baby is crawling up the stairs."

The baby is climbing the stairs too, but an adult going up the stairs normally is also climbing the stairs, so "climbing" doesn't capture the baby's action exactly.